# move files, with spaces in filename, from specific date to other folder within win-batch

Tags: batch-file, filenames, spaces

currently I'm using the following code to move files from previuos month to a archive-folder within a batch-file:

```
    FOR /f "tokens=5" %%f IN ('dir %~2 /A-D ^|find "%day%.%prevmonth%.%year%"') DO MOVE....
```

if I included a "delimter=", to make it also work for files with spaces in the filename, the token-syntax will not work anymore due to the delimter will result to a whole string. So it results to a single token with the complete dir-string which I cannot use.

```
    FOR /f "tokens=1 delims=" %%f IN ('dir %~2 /A-D ^|find "%tag%.%vormonat%.%jahr%"') DO ( 
echo %~2\%%f)

    Output: D:\Temp\Archive_TEST\Source\27.09.2018  11:37 AM             2,927 FILE_F9671598-2886-4fa6-8CBC-63022AAE58BB F9671598-2886-4fa6-8CBC-63022AAE58BB.xml
```

How can I combine the token-syntax an the delimter to make it works for files with spaces in the name?

Thanx!

Comment: `FOR /f "tokens=4*" %%f IN ('…') DO echo "%~2\%%g"` where the `…` ellipsis means `dir %~2 /A-D ^|find "%tag%.%vormonat%.%jahr%"`

Comment: Can you not instead use `ForFiles`, or `RoboCopy` with `/Mov`, by checking the file modified date.

Comment: works fine - thank you!